# Build WCF web service that listens for inbound events

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a external vendor that provides event notification functionality to its down stream clients. They have asked us to do the following steps to implement event notification within our company to receive notifications from external vendor. I have provided actual wording in bold of event notifications as listed in the vendor web site.

**In order to use our Event Notifications within a real-time integration scenario with us, you need to...**

**Create a service that implements our "Notification" WSDL The latest
WSDL for our "Notification" service can be found within our API
Documentation under the "Notification" service section. The
SOAP-message that is send from Workday to your service pass along a
unique identifier for the event (Event_ID) that used in the call-back
to Workday to retrieve additional information for the event**

I already built a WCF web service shell and created a service reference to the Notification WSDL as published in the external vendor site. After that I am not sure what I need to do. The web service needs to do these two steps explained below..

1. When the event occurs on external vendor side a notification message is sent out based on the end point configured on vendor side. So my web service should actively listen for these messages. Once the message is received , i will trap the event ID and make a call back to fetch more data about the data.
2. Once I have the event data, I will process it as per our business logic (I am OK here)

Need help with Step 1, kinda new to building a consuming web service listening for outside events .. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I assume you are looking to handle this message https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/Notification/v14/Receive_Notification.html

Answer (score 2):

You will need to give the vendor a URL to your application - which may mean either

1) hosting on a public facing server and developing on that

2) having some sort of vpn from vendor site to yours so they can talk directly to your server

3) get your infrastructure guys to set up some rule on the firewall to allow requests from the vendor site (IP address restriction) to be routed directly to your development machine

Option 3) is my preferred option for development (simple) and then 1) for long term hosting.

Comment: We will go with the third option. However my question is how do i build the web service to handle these notifications ?

Comment: @Shaun Wilde A more secure approach to opt 3 is to have the service hosted in your DMZ, and put the messages in a queue which is then actively pulled by some entity behind your firewalls. The less ports that are open in your infrastructure, the better.

Comment: @havardhu - I agree - but he wants to develop against it; so your way would require deploying an untested application - or of course making his own client to push test messages - In response to his comment  was thinking of messages (perhaps NServiceBus) as well as the wsdl utility or svcutil.

Comment: @wcfvemi - If it's a simple service; wsdl.exe is the simplest way to make a service. However I assume you would want to use WCF it seems that the svcutil can be used - see this blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/24/wsdl-first-development-with-wcf.aspx

Comment: As explained above I already sourced in the vendor notification WSDL and created a service reference (proxy class) in my web service. I do not know what to do after that .. what is my next step in the web service creation ? how do I make the web service "listen" for outside events that is what I need help with?

Comment: You haven't explained what sort of service you have created i.e. a simple one (.asmx based) or a WCF one. an .asmx is simple as there is a file that you supply to your vendor i.e. http://domain.goes.here/blahblah/notifications.asmx - a wcf one will usually (not always) have entries in the web.config configuration file - unfortunately the comment section is not suitable for relaying complex information.

Comment: It is a WCF we service. https://domain.com/inbound/Notifications.svc is setup and accessible to the vendor..but I am not sure if i have the web service coded to process inbound messages. I just created a service reference to the WSDL provided by the vendor.

Comment: Then why not create your own client test harness and push messages against the server and thus your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but there is an answer. svcutil can do this for you.

svcutil.exe /language:C# /out:MyService.cs Notification.wsdl /syncOnly

This will generate most of what you need, but it also gives you the Client code which isn't required. You can delete that part from the MyService.cs file it generates. If you are using .NET 4.5, you can add /serviceContract option and it will only generate the server-specific code.

This sounds like you're writing a webservice for [Workday Notifications](https://community.workday.com/custom/developer/API/Notification/v20/Notification.wsdl). This wsdl uses a few enumerations which svcutil does not transfer to the generated .cs file. If you care about that, you'll need to change those string properties into enums with the range of values specified in the wsdl manually.